# "Same as" in CSS?

Tags: css

In CSS is it possible to say "same as x"? For example:

```
div.red
{
  color: red;
}

div#red
{
  same-as: div.red;
}
```

I know I could do `div.red, div#red {` but I want to have the the two in separate files without having to copy the entire style block.

Comment: No, but I think you can using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: There's not. But I wish there was :) I would also recommend SASS or LESS which lets you do similar things.

Comment: If javascript is an option: with jQuery you could do `$('div#red').css('color', jQuery('div.red').css('color'))`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in CSS. The correct way is to use correct markup, in such a way, that if you define a `red` class in your `#red` element:

```
<div id="red" class="red"></div>
```

then your `div#red` element will inherited all the style from `div.red`. You dont need to do anything fancy in your css. Your css can simply be

```
div.red {
  color: red;
}

div#red {
  /* something specific to #red */
}
```

Remember, that you can have more than one class in a single element, so you can combine styles coming from multiples classes.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand how to use ids and classes, I just wanted a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot handle 'variables', but the LESS CSS framework was created to handle such a situation (and many more in the same vein):

Here is a sample from the [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org) site:

```
// LESS example - re-using a color setting

@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```